# Multiple Gradle bootJar Configurations - Different mainClass Attributes?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, kotlin

I have a Gradle/Spring Boot build using a `.kts` (Kotlin Style) Gradle build file. (That last part might not matter.)

My Spring Boot application has two different classes that can be used to start it, one for "client" mode and one for "server" mode.

I have a single `bootJar` task that looks like:

```
tasks.bootJar {
    mainClassName = "com.me.ClientApplication"
}
```

So by default when I run `./gradlew build bootJar`, I get a *client version* of the JAR that when run with `java -jar theJar.jar`, executes the `ClientApplication` class.

However, I would also like to publish a **second JAR** that has a different `mainClassName` and runs `com.me.ServerApplication` instead.

How should I approach this? I'm fairly new to Gradle - should I be providing the `mainClassName` to the `./gradlew` command to override it? Or can I define separate tasks like `clientBootJar` and `serverBootJar` that will produce separate artifacts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your configuration is mutually exclusive (can't have two main files), I would say that having two tasks would be optimal:

```
tasks.bootJarClient {
    mainClassName = "com.me.ClientApplication"
}

tasks.bootJarClient {
    mainClassName = "com.me.ServerApplication"
}
```

Other approach is to use properties, but it makes more sense mostly if you have much greater variance.

Now to make a custom task, in your `build.gradle.kts` add something along those lines (didn't test it with SpringBoot specifically):

```
open class BootJarClient : BootJar() {
   override mainClassName = "YourClientClassName"
}

tasks.register<BootJarClient>("bootJarClient") {
    group = "Other"
}

// Server is basically the same
```

Naming of the properties are taken from [GitHub sources](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/aef92b9295f62d008faa9ab79905a474bf3496f3/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/gradle/tasks/bundling/BootJar.java#L85).

Comment: How should I define these as new tasks/definitions? (For subclasses of `bootJar`) Currently they seem to be interpreted as advanced configuration for tasks that don't yet exist. https://imgur.com/a/VAO4DiR

Comment: Let me answer you tomorrow, did something very similar with GradleKT, need to get this code.

Comment: Zero rush, I appreciate you steering me in the right direction. I'm continuing to read up on this area as well.

Comment: Added custom task definitions. Didn't check if `BooJar` would resolve automatically yet, though.